# create 2d list of sets

Tags: java, arrays, collections, interface, set

I am trying to do a 2d grid/array where each cell is a set. For the purpose I use the following code as an example

```
             List<Set<Integer>> grid = new ArrayList<Set<Integer>>();
             // In this line Set is underlined as error
             grid.add(new Set<Integer>());
             grid.get(0).add(2);
```

but it says - "Cannot instantiate the type Set". Basically I want to instantiate a new list dimension and to each of this dimension the cells should be sets? And then comes the question how do I iterate efficiently through this grid?

Answer (score 0):

`Set` is just an Interface, you neeed to instanciate a specific implementation of Set, for example `HashSet`.